# Почему запятые при указание значений(десятичные числа), line-height, процентов, и других, в опере, в консоле, выбиваются как ошибка?

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такая задача возникла..............................................

Comment: так, может указывать **точку** ?

Answer (score 4):

В *CSS* числа с плавающей точкой указываются через точку, а не через запятую, напр.

```
flex: 0 0 49.5%;
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то это "особенность" языков программирования

Comment: Нет, так в принципе правильно писать. Число с плавающей ТОЧКОЙ. Почему в школах нас приучают присать запятую - не ясно

Comment: @Object417 просто в России целая часть числа от дробной традиционно отделяется запятой, поэтому  для обозначения того же понятия исторически используется термин «плавающая запятая» ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯